# Cordova Windows app stops working

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-10-universal

I have a Apache Cordova Windows Universal application 64bit and it was working fine perfectly till the latest Windows 10 update 1607. It keeps crashing on plugin "diagnostic" initialization.

Getting error "diagnostic" is undefined from my javascript.

How can I figure out the exact problem.

Please help.

Thanks,
MG

Comment: Try reinstalling the plugin and check if  `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` object is empty.

Comment: I am able to fix the issue. Actually the plugin was not initialized properly before using it. After the windows update it might be little slow to initialize. Anyway I added all other code just inside the "deviceready" event. Now its working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix the issue. Actually the plugin was not initialized properly before using it. After the windows update it might be little slow to initialize. Anyway I added all other code just inside the "deviceready" event. Now its working fine. Thanks